# Get which plugin sets a specified variable?

Tags: neovim, conceal

Is there a way to know which installed Vim/Neovim plugin sets a specified variable?
For example, I use Neovim 1.5-dev with the following plugins installed:

```
morhetz/gruvbox
tomasr/molokai
mhartington/oceanic-next
ryanoasis/vim-devicons
vim-airline/vim-airline
Yggdroot/indentLine
chrisbra/Colorizer
tpope/vim-commentary
tpope/vim-repeat
tpope/vim-surround
tpope/vim-unimpaired
tpope/vim-fugitive
tpope/vim-vinegar
godlygeek/tabular
junegunn/fzf
junegunn/fzf.vim
majutsushi/tagbar
Shougo/deoplete.nvim
carlitux/deoplete-ternjs
Raimondi/delimitMate
mattn/emmet-vim
ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags
neomake/neomake
andreshazard/vim-freemarker
```

My problem is that when I open a Json file I cannot see double quotes characters. I set in my *init.vim* `set conceallevel=0`, but this is overwritten by some plugin to `conceallevel=2` and I would like to know which plugin overwrite this setting.

Opening a Json file in Neovim with `nvim -u NONE` I can see double quotes, so it has to be a plugin.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: `:verbose set conceallevel`.  However, this only works for options (see `:h options`), not variables.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know how to define `conceallevel`...now I know thath the correct word is *option*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `:help :verbose` to inspect the value of an option (they are "options", not "variables") *and* see where it was last defined:

```
:verbose set conceallevel?
```

Note that you must use the question mark to inspect boolean options while it doesn't change anything for other types so… stay safe, always use the question mark.

Comment: Awesome! `verbose set conceallevel?` reports that this option is set by indentLine plugin...thank you!